# Views Block Issue

Tags: views

I created a views block where I put 3 fields (thumbnail, title and body) from content type nodes. It was all good for a while, but few days ago it started to display in a wierd way, so I checked on FF console and I found that the first views row was containing the next 2 rows!

Any idea on what's happening to this block? Is there any setting that I could possibly check on by mistake and that's what makes this block work that way?

[image: Unknown Behaviour from views block]

Comment: Probably some missing `</div>` anywhere on your site.

Comment: Yup, it wasn't a missing </div>, but a div tag on the "edit resume" field that made the first node to break, it is read as a string, not HTML code. Thanks for your help!